# Java substring a string on every closing html markup

Tags: java, string

I have a string which contains HTML markup like the below:

```
<b> Hi </b> i'm a <i> beautifull </i> <u> string </u>
```

I need to split the string after each html closing markup and get the markup in a variable and text in another variable like the below:

```
startMarkup: <b>  text: Hi     endMarkup: </b>
startMarkup:      text: i'm    endMarkup: 
startMarkup: <i>  text: beautifull  endMarkup: </i>
startMarkup: <font size="5"> text: string endMarkup: </font>
```

Please suggest a good algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: Have a look at regex

Comment: Try: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)  or https://jsoup.org/ or plain regexp.

Comment: I found this to be an excellent resource for learning how to use RegEx: https://regexone.com/. To test your own RegExs locally, you can download something like this: http://regexsr.oxgva.com/

Comment: I know RegEx but I don't know how it can help me now, the best I can it's to get pair of markup but I don't have the text between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
//'main' method must be in a class 'Rextester'.
//Compiler version 1.8.0_111

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
public static void main(String args[])
{
    List<String> startmarkups = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> endmarkups = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
    String s1 = "<b> Hi </b> i'm a <i> beautifull </i> <u> string </u>";
    //Get startmarkup and endmarkups into respective array
    String mk[] = s1.split(">");
    for(int i = 0; i < mk.length; i++){
        System.out.println(mk[i]);
        if(!mk[i].trim().startsWith("<")){
            if(mk[i].indexOf("<") >= 0){
                if(mk[i].indexOf("/") >= 0){
                    endmarkups.add("</"+(mk[i].split("/")[1])+">");
                    startmarkups.add("<"+(mk[i].split("<")[1])+">");
                }else{
                    endmarkups.add("");
                    startmarkups.add("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Get text into texts array
    for(int i = 0; i < mk.length; i++){
        if(!mk[i].trim().startsWith("<")){
            if(mk[i].indexOf("<") >= 0)
                texts.add((mk[i].split("<")[0]));
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < startmarkups.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("Startmarkup: " + startmarkups.get(i) + "\t");
        System.out.print("Text: " + texts.get(i) + "\t");
        System.out.print("Endmarkup: " + endmarkups.get(i) + "\t");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Replace the s1 variable with the html string.